# Minimum Length for Domain Name

Tags: domain-name

I need to make validation for domain name length in my PHP programming. Can you please suggest me min and max length required for domain name. I tried to find out in google but I am unable to find out proper solution for it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to  [this resource](http://gawker.com/318368/the-shortest-domain-name-ever) you can find websites with single letter and `com`. I hope that will help you.

Comment: I was try in godaddy hosting server they don't allow me y.com or 1 letter length.

Comment: Maybe it is already in use or some hostings has their own domain validations.

Comment: @VipulJethva According to [Nic AG](http://www.nic.ag/rules.htm):
`Domain names cannot have more than 63 characters, not including .AG, .COM.AG, .NET.AG, .ORG.AG, .EDU.AG, .GOV.AG, ETC. Minimum length of a domain name is 1 character, not including extensions. However, all 1 character domain names are reserved by the Registry.`

Comment: @NoodleOfDeath Will you please give me any site name which has 1 or 2 characters on it? Just for my knowledge

Comment: @VipulJethva Sure! Amazon beat Apple to [a.co](https://a.co); Google is [g.co](https://g.co); Facebook [m.me](https://m.me); Twitter [t.co](https://t.co); Wordpress [w.org](https://w.org). You can find even more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-letter_second-level_domain)

Comment: @VipulJethva as of 1993, one letter domain names became reserved for registry; the examples I listed above were reserved before that international decision and grandfathered in and allowed to remain.

Comment: Another good reference is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-letter_second-level_domain

Comment: `x.com` was owned by Elon Musk and then PayPal for a while.

Answer (score 1):

The max limit is set out here https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#section-2.3.4.

Label limit 63 characters (strings between periods)

Name limit 255 characters (total of the strings combined together)

Comment: minimum != maximum

Answer (score -3):

Minimum Domain Name Length Is 3 Characters and Maximum of 63. Hosting for 1 or 2 characters only is too expensive and you might not want it for its not yet open for public use.

Comment: > No one goes there anymore, it's too crowded. 


g.co is a very commonly used link shortener, for example.